# Refresh auth token in Ktor while using koin

Tags: access-token, ktor, koin, auth-token, koin-scope

I was using Koin as dependency Injection library to create the ktor HttpClient:

```
val AppModule = module {
    single { provideClientService() }
}

fun provideClientService(preferences: SharedPreferences): HttpClient {

install(Auth){
    bearer {
        loadTokens {
            BearerTokens(sharedPreferences.getString("accessToken",""))      
        }
    }
}}
```

but after the user login the accessToken is not updated.

I think it is because of the different scopes in koin. there is 3 kind of scopes in koin:

- **single definition** : create an object that persists with the entire container lifetime (can't be dropped).
- **factory definition** : create a new object each time. Short life. No persistence in the container (can't be shared).
- **scoped definition** : create an object that is persistent tied to the associated scope lifetime.

so I changed the client definition to factory , because I want it to be updated after getting a new token. and now I wonder is it correct?

```
val AppModule = module {
    factory { provideClientService() }
}
```

Comment: The single definition should be enough here because the description doesn't say anything about updates of an object's internal state. Could you please describe how an access token is updated?

Comment: you are right, I edited my post. I get accessToken from preferences which is null before login and then get updated.

Comment: The handler for `loadTokens` is called only when an access token isn't loaded yet. An access token can be updated if it should be refreshed (the `refreshTokens` method) or the token's storage is cleared (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69993453/13963150). Please tell me in what case you experience a problem.

Comment: before you login to your app accessToken is empty and after login I wanted my accessToken to be added to my ktor Client but because I defined it as single it doesn't create a new client object so the accessToken remained empty and I get unAutherized  error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem. Please see the gist with a code https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/43bb6b1461c5dc1ad045b94e673ddcc0